# dataTables Date sorting and MomentJS

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I'm using dataTables with MomentJS to sort a table with dates.

This sorts/works fine:

```
    <table id="testTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
            <tr>
                        <th class="all">Title</th>
                <th class="tablet-p tablet-l desktop  text-center">Category</th> 
                <th class="tablet-p tablet-l desktop  text-center">Date</th> 
                </tr>
        </thead>
                
            
                <!-- TABLE BODY -->
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td ><a href='#' >Test 1</a></td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >2</td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >01 Oct 2020</td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><a href='#' >Test 2</a></td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >8</td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >01 Apr 2020</td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><a href='#' >Test 2</a></td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >2</td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >10 Sep 2020</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><a href='#' >Test 1</a></td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >2</td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >20 Aug 2020</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><a href='#' >Test 5</a></td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >2</td>
                        <td  class="text-center" align="center" >12 Dec 2020</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

but I would like to sort on this date:

```
<td  class="text-center" align="center" >01 - 12 Oct 2020</td>
```

Ideally I would like to use something like this so the data is only sorted on the second part of the date:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('[%wildcard% -] DD MMM YYYY');
$('#testTable').DataTable();
```

Is this possible or is there a different solution?

Comment: So you just want to sort on date? Or last part of date? So, in your example sort on `12 Oct 2020`?

Comment: Hello, yes full date would be great but I would be happy with the last part of date `12 Oct 2020`

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution - I used php to create a time stamp from the last part of the date and add it to a data attribute to sort on that instead:

`<td  class="text-center" align="center" data-sort="1602460800">01 - 12 Oct 2020</td>`